# Calculation for IC lifetime for supply voltage overvoltage

Tags: power, integrated-circuit, reliability, lifetime, silicon

What calculation can be used to calculate the lifetime of an embedded processor (<28nm process) when subject to a slight overvoltage?
The supply rail in question is for analog portions of the circuit (Clock PLL and SerDes receive).

0.87 to 0.93V - Recommended operating voltage

0.945V -absolute maximum

0.938V - voltage measured during manufacturing test.

The supply voltage has been set high - 0.923V centred and using 0.1% resistors but remote sense of core voltage has added unaccounted 6mV. Rework unwanted outcome, I need to explore lifetime implications of this overvoltage.

I tried searching google and stack exchange for clues but all I can find is the temperature effects on IC lifetime.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "one-size-fits-all" answer to this question. You need to contact the manufacturer and get their accelerated lifetime test data. It is likely that if you are using the device within its maximum specifications that there will be no data regarding small variations in supply voltage.

Otherwise, you will need to do life testing yourself.

Remember that these effects can vary dramatically from one manufacturing lot to another.

Comment: Depending on the exact scenario, the more practical option might well be to build in better protection against overvoltages.  You should certainly have accurate cost projections for that option before making a final decision.